# Is it better to compress every line individually or compress an entire file?

Tags: performance, file, architecture, compression

My use case is that I'm writing entries to a file throughout the day. I can either write these entries compressed, or compress the entire file after the fact. These files can get fairly big (~10 GB uncompressed) and I'm writing to multiple files at the same time. Some other considerations are that I can split up the files to smaller granularites to address the buffer issue for compressing per file. There probably isn't a definitive right or wrong answer to this, but just seeing if there are other considerations that I should look at.

Once compressed, these files will be uploaded to some sort of storage medium for archival purposes and possible later analysis.

**Compress Per Line**

| Pros | Cons |
| --- | --- |
| More space efficient while writing | More Complicated to Implement |
| More space efficient while reading since I can decompress on a per entry granularity | Less efficient in terms of disk space usage vs compressing an entire file |

**Compress Per File**

| Pros | Cons |
| --- | --- |
| Better Compression on a per file basis since there is more data that can be compressed | Requires a bigger buffer of disk space to handle writes throughout the day before compressing |
| Simpler to implement, write normally to file and compress afterwards using simple linux tools |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have really, really long lines, you will get almost no compression on a single line. Have you tried it?

You can get the best of both worlds by accumulating lines until you have enough to compress, and then write those to the file. [gzlog](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/gzlog.h) does that.

Comment: `gzlog` does seem to be a good in between, I'll take a look. Thank you

Comment: yes the lines are not that long and there isn't much compression. I'm a fan of compressing the file as a whole but I do see the issue with needing a certain buffer space to write to before compression which can be fairly large. I think `gzlog` can address both concerns.